# RenderBody error in second Layout in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

> **Error:** The following sections have been defined but have not been
>   rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml":
>   "partialviewBanner".

First time posting StackOverflowflow, so please excuse me for the bad question.

When I try to call `actionresult` from a `new controller` with a new _layout, the `renderbody()` in the new layout, still retrievers the `oldIndex.cshtml` and not the defined `newIndex.cshtml`. Why is this? The goal is to have a adminLayout with its own views. So that when the method is called, a new layout with a new view is set.

```
    UserController:
     [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LoggInnModal(LogInVM brukerlogin)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CustomerVM kunde = new CustomerBLL().UserLogIn(brukerlogin);
                if (kunde != null)
                {
                    Session["Kunde"] = kunde;

                    if(kunde.Admin)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("AdmIndex", "Admin");
                    }
                    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
                }
            }

     public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Admin
        public ActionResult AdmIndex()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    _ViewStart.cshtml:
    @using Oblig1.Model

@{
    CustomerVM customer = (CustomerVM)HttpContext.Current.Session["Customer"];
}

@{
    if (customer != null)
    {
        if (customer.Admin)
        {
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
        }
        else
        {
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }
    } else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

}
```

Everything until now seems that it is working, but when the browser reads the AdminLayout.cshtml errors occurs.

Now when the reader enters this section, the renderbody still calls the other `.cshtml` and not the one defined in the AdminController. In this case, it crashes because the required partialviews does not exist in the new layout.

```
    _AdminLayout.cshtml
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       **This is where it calls the oldIndex.cshtml and not the newIndex.cshtml**
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.
If my question is not defined enough please tell me.

Comment: You can simplify your layout selection code by using the Null-conditional operator `if (customer?.Admin) { _AdminLayout } else { _Layout }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hehe seems the layout situation was fully functional. The problem was that a modal LogOn  javascript function made the webpage reload with the old layout.

```
function LoggInnModal(resultat) {
var melding;
try {
    melding = JSON.parse(resultat);
} catch (feil) {
    melding = null;
}
$("#epostmelding").empty();
$("#passordmelding").empty();
if (melding != null) {
    if (melding == "admin") {
        //sets the admin.frontpage
        window.location.replace(AppUrl.Admin); //SOLUTION!
    } else {
        if (melding == "Oppgi epostadresse") {
            $("#epostmelding").append(melding);

        } else {
            $("#passordmelding").append(melding);
        }
    }
} else {
    $("#loggInnModal").modal("hide");
    window.location.reload(); //PROBLEM!

    console.log();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have defined a section named "partialviewBanner" in your mater layout page but not included anything for that section in your view.

Comment: That might be the problem, but I don't want that section or any elements from the mater layout page. So if I set    @RenderSection("partialviewBanner", false) the webpage just gets the oldIndex.cshtml without that partialview. Might be that my understanding of a mater layout is lacking.